# Remote Desktop Issue

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

Working from home, I use Remote Desktop with my workplace VPN via FortiNet client.

I keep having the issue where it will kick me out (saying lost connection), and will not work again until I restart my computer. Sometimes I get kicked out after 5 minutes, sometimes 3 hours, that part seems random to me.

Is there any way avoid having to restart my computer?

Comment: Instead of restarting your computer, try just restarting your networking.

Comment: How does one go about doing that? ipconfig? I should say I am using a Windows OS.

Comment: Does your internet connection go off when that happens? Or is it just the VPN connection?

Comment: Just the VPN. After I get the lost connection, when I try to remote back in, I get the standard message saying either the computer is off, or does not allow remote desktop connection etc. After I restart my computer, all is fine and I can remote back in.